# Concatenate 2 or more columns and using within a LIKE predicate?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Currently I have a query which looks bit like this:

```
select * from person
where person.firstname LIKE '%firstname_fragment%' OR 
      person.lastname  LIKE '%lastname_fragment%'
```

How can you join the two columns into a SQL WHERE predicate which does something like this instead?

```
person.firstname + person.lastname LIKE '%firstname_fragment
lastname_fragment%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Oracle.  That would be SQL Server syntax.  You want:

```
where person.firstname || ' ' || person.lastname LIKE '%firstname_fragment lastname_fragment%'
```

I added the space because you have a space in the pattern argument to `like`.

One more comment.  This is different from the query you have in your question.  The equivalent query would be more like:

```
select * from person
where person.firstname LIKE '%firstname_fragment%' AND
      person.lastname  LIKE '%lastname_fragment%'
```

Comment: I agree with adding the space, I just might add % at the end of the first name and beginning of the last name fragments leaving the space in between to match first query -- depends on OPs needs though.